# How to put windows 7 iso file on dvd

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I am a Linux user who switched from Windows (still had dual boot) but during Ubuntu 13.10 install something went wrong, because the windows partition volume was corrupted. In the end after trying many things to fix the issue, I simply got rid of windows 7 overall and wanted to do a clean install of both operating systems. At the point I already downloaded Windows 7. I'm just wondering in which way I would be able to put the Windows ISO file on a DVD so I can install it.

http://www.pcworld.com/article/248995/how_to_install_windows_7_without_the_disc.html

is the website I referred, but for step 3 for where it shows where to get the program, the link just redirects to Windows help and is of no use. Is there another program that can be downloaded which does the same thing so I can re-install Windows and put it on a DVD?

Comment: The dvd/usb tool is a dvd burner that only works with a windows iso.  The standard ubuntu dvd burner should work with the windows iso.

Answer (score 1):

i dont realy get it Oo
you have a .ISO file to put on a DVD ?
if yes here is the solution:
just start your burning software (e.g.: Brasero) click on "burn image" choose your .ISO-file and insert a proper CD/DVD and start burning.
Is that what you need ?

Comment: okay, thats all i needed to know is which program to use to burn the iso file. thanks, sorry if confusing, my english is not great